# Excel VBA: why am I unable to nest two worksheet functions, within a loop? Works in Excel but not in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Please see VBA code below. The loop runs fine when I run the random number generator function (RandBetween) alone, but crashes when I wrap it with the beta probability function (Beta_Inv). The nested Excel formula works fine and looks like this: = BETA.INV(RAND(), 0.5, 0.5, 0, 1). I can´t get it to work in VBA and I don´t want to have to refer to the formula in the Worksheet, for speed reasons. I highlight below the line where the error occurs (again, works fine if I remove the Application.Beta_Inv function).

```
Sub ArrayFillRange()
    Dim CellsDown As Long, CellsAcross As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Array1() As Double
    Dim Range1 As Range
     
'   Change these values to alter array dimensions
    CellsDown = 1000
    CellsAcross = 1
     
'   Redimension array
    ReDim Array1(1 To CellsDown, 1 To CellsAcross)
     
'   Set worksheet range for output
    Set Range1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(CellsDown, CellsAcross))
 
'   Fill the array with random variables from inverse of cum beta probability density function
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = 0
    For i = 1 To CellsDown
        For j = 1 To CellsAcross
            Randomize
            ' the next line
            Array1(i, j) = Application.Beta_Inv(Round(Application.RandBetween(0, 100) / 100, 2), 0.5, 0.5, 0, 1)
        Next j
    Next i
   
'   Output array values to worksheet
    Range1.Value = Array1
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `Round` is not the same as the `ROUND` worksheet function. What is the error message?

Comment: Most likely `Round(Application.RandBetween(0, 100) / 100, 2)` is returning 0, causing `Application.Beta_Inv` to return an error.

Comment: try declaring the array as Variant not Double.

Comment: @ScottCraner for me simply changing the array to variant from double makes it work. With double it crashes on 40th i loop iteration - do you have any insight as to why that makes it work?

Comment: @JohnnieL - `Application.Beta_Inv` will return an error value if the first argument equals 0. That will be an automatic type mismatch, because an error value cannot be coerced to a `Double`. Though I don't agree with Scott here. I think the proper answer would be to test if the the first argument is 0, and not keep the error value.

Comment: or change the RANDBETWEEN to (1,100)  so it will never be `0`

Comment: One note I suggested the variant to show the error.

Comment: Thank you!!! I changed the RANDBETWEEN so it is never 0 nor 1, either of which results in an error when running Beta_Inv. So I´m using Application.RandBetween(0.0000001, 100 - 0.0000001) and it works fine now. THANKS!!!